# jQuery Ajax call doesn't work with me at any cost in MVC 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a view that contains a dropdown and when I select a particular option I want to display the data returned in a partial view. At any cost the ajax function is not working. I am using VS 2013 MVC 4.

Tried to change the latest jquery from http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js but still doesn't work. Ajax call are not working that is it. Breaking my head from last 1 day.

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<TTracking.CareWebService.ClinicGroup>
@using System.Globalization;
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Appointment";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutWebsite.cshtml";
}

<h2></h2>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {

    $("#CategoryID").change( function (event) {
        var userId = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("GetDoctors", "Controller")",
            data: { id : userId },
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "html",    
        success: function (data) {       
            $("#divPartialView").html( data ); 
        }
    });
});

});

</script>



<div class="dropdown">
    @Html.DropDownList("CategoryID", 
(List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Categories, "Select Clinic")
</div>

<div id="divPartialView">

</div>
```

Controller that returns Partial View:

```
public PartialViewResult GetDoctors(int id)
    {
        var res = new CWS.DoctorsCollection();

        try
        {
            CWS.CWSSoapClient cl = new 
CWS.CWSSoapClient();

            res = cl.getDoctorsByClinicGroup(id.ToString(), 
"sercuritykey");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

        return PartialView("DoctorsList",res.Doctors);

    }
```

Comment: Time to debug.  When you use your browser's debugging tools, are there any errors on the JavaScript console?  In the network panel, is an AJAX request being made?  Does it contain the data you expect?  What is the server's response?  Is it what you expect?  When you debug your server-side code, what specifically happens?  What were you expecting to happen?  Why?  If it's not being made, is that `change` handler being invoked at all?  Stop "breaking your head" and start testing/validating each operation in your code.

Comment: As you've mentioned to test and debug, I added the error function to the ajax call I found out that there was error in the partial view. Once it fixed, thanks God, ajax started to work and my partial view got populated. Thanks...